# Not sure what is wrong with expression URL link

Tags: javascript, url, reporting-services, hyperlink

I have this expression link to a report and nothing happens when I run the report. Please spot anything wrong here.

```
="javascript:void window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl &
 "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" & Globals!ReportFolder &
 "/NewAssetsReport&rc:Parameters=true" & "&empno=" & Parameters!empno.Value &
 "&branchno=" & Parameters!branchno.Value &
 "')"
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Nothing happens*?  Please provide specific details about what you expected and what actually happened, ideally with screenshots.

Comment: I mean when click on the link to this report then the report not show up and no error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the JavaScript call. You were missing the opening and closing parenthesis `()`.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Globals!ReportServerUrl &
 "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?" & Globals!ReportFolder &
 "/NewAssetsReport&rc:Parameters=true" & "&empno=" & Parameters!empno.Value &
 "&branchno=" & Parameters!branchno.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

I did a diff between the posted version and my answer

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you running the report on the report server or your visual studio? It will only work on the report server.

Comment: Any luck with this?